# How to mock one method with different parameters multiple times?

Tags: java, mockito

I have some testing method:

```
@Test
public void test_method() {
    MyObj mock = mock(MyObj.class);
    when(mock.get("testName", "1")).thenReturn("Result1");
    when(mock.get("test", "2")).thenReturn("rrrr");
}
```

when I trying run this method I had exception:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.PotentialStubbingProblem: 
Strict stubbing argument mismatch. Please check:

Typically, stubbing argument mismatch indicates user mistake when writing tests.
Mockito fails early so that you can debug potential problem easily.
However, there are legit scenarios when this exception generates false negative signal:
  - stubbing the same method multiple times using 'given().will()' or 'when().then()' API
    Please use 'will().given()' or 'doReturn().when()' API for stubbing.
  - stubbed method is intentionally invoked with different arguments by code under test
    Please use default or 'silent' JUnit Rule (equivalent of Strictness.LENIENT).
For more information see javadoc for PotentialStubbingProblem class.
```

How can I mock this method?

Comment: In your test you do not do anything with the class under test, hence the mocks are not used. Please add a [mre].

Comment: Check this out: we can't read minds.  Include the class definition of the `MyObj` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message tells you:

> stubbing the same method multiple times using `'given().will()'` or `'when().then()'` API
>   Please use `'will().given()'` or `'doReturn().when()'` API for stubbing.

Comment: That error message refers to the case `when(foo.get("1")).thenReturn(true);when(foo.get("1")).thenReturn(false)` that should be written as `doReturn(true,false).when(foo).get("1")`; (at least I suppose)

Comment: 'will().given()' or 'doReturn().when()' produces the same error

Answer (score 1):

You can use [any()](https://www.journaldev.com/21876/mockito-argument-matchers-any-eq#mockito-argument-matchers-8211-any) to mock one method with different parameters. any() will be used as a dynamic variable.

e.g doReturn(order).when(orderRepository).save(any(Order.class));

I was saving orderRepository with 2 different Order parameters so I have used any with Order class.

Answer (score 0):

For me worked add the annotation @MockitoSettings(strictness = Strictness.LENIENT)

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension::class)
@MockitoSettings(strictness = Strictness.LENIENT)
```

Comment: Need to be careful with this as you may risk to have just a useless test, hiding potential issues.